# Benefit of Membership or Benefits of Membership?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, grammatical-number

I am designing a brochure for a local club.  The text, which was provided by one of the members, includes a list titled, "Benefit of Membership," followed by bulleted line items such as Volunteering, Camaraderie, Educational Meetings, etc.

Had I written the copy, I would have made the title plural, "Benefits of Membership," as the list contains more than one item. But the more I look at it,  the more I am not sure if the singular is also correct.   I hesitate to point out an error I am not entirely sure of.

Answer (score 2):

Will you be listing more than one benefit? If so, then it should be benefits. It is a noun in this use.

The situation for benefit would be as a verb or as a singlar noun.

Answer (score 0):

It is the title of a list, so it should be *Benefits of Membership*. I think if you remove *of Membership* from the title, you will no longer be able to convince yourself of the correctness of *Benefit of Membership*.